# JS OpenLayers get ol/Feature values on click

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am using `OpenLayers` and I want to get all values from Marker (`ol.Feature`).
You can see in [docs](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Feature-Feature.html) it is possible to add any value to `ol.Feature`.

```
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Polygon from 'ol/geom/Polygon';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';

var feature = new Feature({
  geometry: new Polygon(polyCoords),
  labelPoint: new Point(labelCoords),
  name: 'My Polygon' // <--- CUSTOM VALUE
});

// get the polygon geometry
var poly = feature.getGeometry();

// Render the feature as a point using the coordinates from labelPoint
feature.setGeometryName('labelPoint');

// get the point geometry
var point = feature.getGeometry();
```

I have a `click` event on map and I want to get those values.

```
this.map.on('click', (args) => {

        this.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(args.pixel, (feature, layer) => {
            // do something
            console.log(feature.values_); // <---- SEEMS LIKE 'PRIVATE' prop
        });
    });
```

It looks like `ol.Feature` has no method for getting these values. Is there any 'nicer' solution than `feature.values_` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all properties using

```
feature.getProperties()
```

or if you just need one, you can do

```
feature.get('name')
```